# Definite integral from Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I'm trying to convert this Riemann Sum into the definite integral, but I'm stuck.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \sum_{k=n}^{2n}   \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k} \right)$$

I know the theory and I solved other exercises. The problem with this one is finding the right guess.

I tried pulling out $n$ from the sum.

Another attempt was to subtitute $$k=\frac{1}{i}$$

Comment: This isn't a Riemann sum. You could use $x-x^3/6<\sin x<x$ to relate this to $$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \sum_{k=n}^{2n}   \frac{\pi}{k}=\pi\,\log2,$$ and you *could* use a Riemann sum for the latter limit, but that's not the only way to show that.